# Java threads calling parent functions

Tags: java

Im making some software written in java, it involves a single 'Parent' class that invokes dozens of classes(nodes) that run in their own thread (extends Thread).

The classes store the parent class as a variable. If the node class invokes a method from the parent class, does each node store a copy of the parent object or do all the nodes act upon the same object? if all nodes act on the same object, do statements in the called function run in the thread of the node or in the thread of the parent class?

EX code:

```
    class parent
    {
        ArrayList<node> nodes = new  ArrayList<node>();
       void createStartNodes()
       {
          for(int i =0; i < 36;++i)
          {
             nodes.put(i,new node(this));
             nodes.get(i).start();
          }
       }
       void callSomeFunc()
       {
           /* things */
       }
    }
class node extends Thread
{
   parent par;
   public node(parent p)
   {
      par=p;
   }
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
     par.callSomeFunc();
  } 
}
```

Comment: You should fix capitalization in your code. If you mean Java's Thread class, it needs to be uppercase to not confuse people.

Comment: If you remove threads from your question, isn't it still the same question?

Comment: They reference the same object, the variables in java are similar to pointers in C.

Comment: I didnt know if running in different threads would affect anything or not. So does the current thread perform the execution of the parents function?

Comment: T_T my eyes... Please capitalize your class names.

Comment: Read about value type vs reference type. Having said that, Java doesn't have value types - everything is object. As such you always reference the same block of memory when pass it around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does each node store a copy of the parent object or do all the nodes act upon the same object?

They each store a pointer to the memory location of the parent object. They indeed act upon the same object.

> if all nodes act on the same object, do statements in the called function run in the thread of the node or in the thread of the parent class?

They run in the thread of the node that tries to modify the parent object. You may want to make sure you use synchronization properly when doing that, for example by using a `synchronized` block. Otherwise, when there is concurrent access to the parent object, you may get incorrect / inconsistent behaviour. Example:

```
class Node extends Thread
{
    Parent par;

    public Node(Parent p)
    {
       par=p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()    
    {
       synchronized(par) {
           par.callSomeFunc();
       }
    } 
}
```

The `synchronized` block will give this thread exclusive access to the parent object.

Also, thread specific logic should be in the `run` method, not in the `start` method.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're confusing things. I just want to clarify these before answering your questions:

- A class does not "run in a thread", because it does not "run". You can run methods, not classes. **A method of a class could be executed in different threads depending on where you called it.**
- When extending the `Thread` class (note the capital T), you should **override the `run()` method, not the `start()` method**, otherwise the multithreading stuff won't happen. However, you indeed **have to *call* `start()`**, defined in the Thread class, which in turn will call your `run()` method in the created thread, as you would expect.
  *[EDIT: this point was apparently solved in the OP's edit]*

That being said, back to your actual questions:

> does each node store a copy of the parent object or do all the nodes
>   act upon the same object?

Every java object (read non-primitive type) is just a reference, you don't pass object values. Therefore, all your nodes store a reference to the same object, because you gave them the reference (`this`) to the same object when calling their constructor.

> do statements in the called function run in the thread of the node or
>   in the thread of the parent class?

<strike>In the current state of your code, you're not overriding `run()` but `start()`, so you don't have multiple threads anyway.</strike> (solved by OP)

The code executed in the `run()` method will be executed in the thread of the node, **even when calling other methods from `run()`**.

*Sidenote: this is because you called `node.start()` properly. If you directly called `node.run()`, it would be executed in the thread from which you call `run()`.*

Answer (score 1):

First of all you **are not** supposed to override the start() method of `Thread` class, you are supposed to call it. And Similarly you are not supposed to call run() method of Thread class, you supposed to override it.

So when you call the method which is written in the your "parent" class from the run() method, it acts in the new instance and its not shared by all the other thread that you have created.

Edit: As you have passed "this" to constructor, they will share the same object.

Comment: "Similarly you are not supposed to call run() method of Thread class, you supposed to call it." Hum hum... Seriously? You're not to call it, but you should call it? ^^'